# How can I removed Powered by Wordpress link in wp.login.php without editing core WP files?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to remove the Powered by Wordpress (wordpress.org) link that is attached to the logo in wo-login.php or else update it without having to edit the core files. Is it possible to do this?

Kyle

Comment: Tried Google? "remove powered by wordpress" results in over 6 million  hits.

Comment: Can you show some code around the element? Perhaps setting the element's display to hidden in your own stylesheet would suffice.

Comment: @j08691 thanks for the reply, most of the results are to remove the powered by link from the footer, also a lot of them target editing the main core files which I dont want to do hence my post here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your theme's `functions.php` file, add this:

```
function my_login_css() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/path_to_dir_in_your_theme/login.css">';
}

add_action('login_head', 'my_login_css');
```

Then just create your custom `login.css` file that makes whatever changes you want.

To change the link and alt text on the login logo from Wordpress.org to the title/url for your site, use these filters in your `functions.php` file:

```
// changing the logo link from wordpress.org to your site 
function my_login_url() { echo bloginfo('url'); }

// changing the alt text on the logo to show your site name 
function my_login_title() { echo get_option('blogname'); }

// calling it only on the login page
add_filter('login_headerurl', 'my_login_url');
add_filter('login_headertitle', 'my_login_title');
```

Comment: hey @Chaser324 its not the css Im worried about, I've already added custom styles, I just want to remove the link thats attached to the logo ive used in place of the Wordpress logo as it still links out to wordpress.org?

Comment: @styler Updated with what I think you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

@Chaser324 is nearly correct, instead of echo'ing the results need to return the result i.e.

```
// changing the logo link from wordpress.org to your site 
function my_login_url() { return bloginfo('url'); }

// changing the alt text on the logo to show your site name 
function my_login_title() { return get_option('blogname'); }

// calling it only on the login page
add_filter('login_headerurl', 'my_login_url');
add_filter('login_headertitle', 'my_login_title');
```

Comment: In the latest version of WP, you'll need return home_url(); instead of return bloginfo('url');